# Minimise the maximum difference between any 2 elements of an array

Tags: greedy

You are given an array and an integer k. How to minimise the maximum difference between any 2 elements of array by changing atmost k elements to any number.
eg: 4,7,4,7,4 and k=2
Change element at index 1,3 to 4. Array becomes 4,4,4,4,4. So maximum difference between any 2 elements becomes 0.

I thought to sort the array and find absolute difference between median and all the numbers and change the number which has biggest difference to the median.
Eg 4,7,4,7,4. Median =4
Array after sorting 4,4,4,7,7
Absolute difference 0,0,0,3,3. SO changed the maximum absolute difference number.